# remove first date in a row and last date in row from an array

Tags: arrays

I have the following array

```
var array1 = ["2020-05-23","2020-05-24","2020-05-25","2020-05-26","2020-05-27","2020-05-28","2020-05-29","2020-05-30","2020-09-12","2020-09-13","2020-09-14","2020-09-15","2020-09-16","2020-09-17","2020-09-18","2020-09-19","2020-05-23","2020-05-24","2020-05-25","2020-05-26","2020-05-27","2020-05-28","2020-05-29","2020-05-30","2020-06-20","2020-06-21","2020-06-22","2020-06-23","2020-06-24","2020-06-25","2020-06-26","2020-06-27","2020-06-28","2020-06-29","2020-06-30","2020-07-01","2020-07-02","2020-07-03","2020-07-04","2020-09-12","2020-09-13","2020-09-14","2020-09-15","2020-09-16","2020-09-17","2020-09-18","2020-09-19"]
```

I want to build 2 new arrays by removing at 1st array last date in a row and second array with first date in a row. Example for dates "2020-05-23","2020-05-24","2020-05-25","2020-05-26","2020-05-27","2020-05-28","2020-05-29","2020-05-30"
I want to remove "2020-05-30" in 1st array and "2020-05-23" at the second array.

So the new arrays will look like

(1st new array with removed last date)

```
    var array2 = ["2020-05-23","2020-05-24","2020-05-25","2020-05-26","2020-05-27","2020-05-28","2020-05-29","2020-09-12","2020-09-13","2020-09-14","2020-09-15","2020-09-16","2020-09-17","2020-09-18","2020-05-23","2020-05-24","2020-05-25","2020-05-26","2020-05-27","2020-05-28","2020-05-29","2020-06-20","2020-06-21","2020-06-22","2020-06-23","2020-06-24","2020-06-25","2020-06-26","2020-06-27","2020-06-28","2020-06-29","2020-06-30","2020-07-01","2020-07-02","2020-07-03","2020-09-12","2020-09-13","2020-09-14","2020-09-15","2020-09-16","2020-09-17","2020-09-18",]
```

and

(2nd new array with removed first date)

```
    var array3 = ["2020-05-24","2020-05-25","2020-05-26","2020-05-27","2020-05-28","2020-05-29","2020-05-30","2020-09-13","2020-09-14","2020-09-15","2020-09-16","2020-09-17","2020-09-18","2020-09-19","2020-05-24","2020-05-25","2020-05-26","2020-05-27","2020-05-28","2020-05-29","2020-05-30","2020-06-21","2020-06-22","2020-06-23","2020-06-24","2020-06-25","2020-06-26","2020-06-27","2020-06-28","2020-06-29","2020-06-30","2020-07-01","2020-07-02","2020-07-03","2020-07-04","2020-09-13","2020-09-14","2020-09-15","2020-09-16","2020-09-17","2020-09-18","2020-09-19"]
```

Comment: is it JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

if you have two array then use..
- Remove the first element: array_shift($array);
- Remove the last element: array_pop($array);

If you want to remove both element (first and last)then...
- array_slice($array, 1, -1);

Comment: as you can see the dates I need to remove are not only at the end of each array. there is a row of dates 23/5/2020 till 30/5/2020 , 12/09/2020 - 19/09/2020, 20/06/2020 - 04/07/2020 and need to remove at first array 30/05/2020 , 19/09/2020 , 04/07/2020 and at second array 23/05/2020, 12/09/2020, 20/06/2020. Array is dynamic from database.

Answer (score 0):

Looking like C# there. If you know the positions are always first and last. 
In that case I think that would be easily accomplished with a new feature in C# 8. Range can break out slices of data from Arrays. Take a look at this: [Microsoft docs range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges)

```
var lastItem = list[..^2];
```

This creates a new array from the seccond to last place in the old array.

```
var slice2 = list[2..];
```

This creates a new array from the seccond position in the old array.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)  with array functions in JavaScript

```
array1.pop();    // Removes the last element from an array and returns only that element. 
var array2 = array1;

array1.shift();  // Removes the first element from an array and returns only that element.
var array3 = array1;

console.log(array2);
console.log(array3);
```